# Create module that throws exception in rails if conditions not met on load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module in a rails 3 app that's included in multiple models. I want to force the app to fail to load if any of the models do not have an appropriate attr_accessor defined. Due to the architecture of the app it's not feasible to include the attr_accessors as a part of the module to be added to the class during the `self.included` function.

Here's what I've tried at present:

```
module MyModule
  def included(base)
    raise "Accessor 'enabled' is not defined in #{base.name}" unless base.method_defined? :enabled
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveModel::Base
  # attr_accessor :enabled
  attr_accessor :attr_1, :attr_2
  include MyModule
end
```

In this instance, I'd want the app to fail to load because `MyModel` does not have an `enabled` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work - on production. In development the classes in app/models are only loaded if used unless you set

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

in config/environments/development.rb. But that makes developing really no fun, since you have to restart your webserver every change to test your changes. On rails 4 you have another configuration option

```
config.eager_load = true
```

So you do not need to cache classes to get the behaviour to have loaded every class on starting your server / console.

If it's really only attribute accessor you check, it's better just to set it on including the module. And if you work with modules in rails: have a look into http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveSupport/Concern
There you can just call attr_accessor :enabled in the included block.